# CAGradientLayer with shouldRasterize causes unwanted line

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, cagradientlayer

I use `CAGradientLayer` in header view of `TableView`. To make scroll smooth I've turned `shouldRasterize` property to YES and it's caused the problem.

Gradient layer is drawn like it has a border. All frames I set in layoutSubviews and all its fields are integers.

Here are screenshots:

How it appears:

[image: How it appears]

How it have to look like:

[image: How it have to look like]

Here is a code related to this gradient layer

```
- (void)createShadow {
    CAGradientLayer *shadowLayer= [CAGradientLayer layer];

    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithWholeRed:236 green:235 blue:236];
    UIColor *destinationColor = [UIColor colorWithWholeRed:248 green:248 blue:250];

    shadowLayer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    shadowLayer.borderWidth = 0;
    shadowLayer.colors = @[(id)startColor.CGColor,(id)destinationColor.CGColor];
    shadowLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    [self.layer addSublayer:shadowLayer];

    self.shadowLayer = shadowLayer; 
}

- (void)updateShadow {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                            self.frame.size.width, ceil(self.frame.size.height * 0.3));
    [self.shadowLayer setFrame:newRect]; 
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self updateShadow];
}
```

Tell me please if you know how to solve this problem)